# WIX Store - Get list of products from their API to show on mobile app

Tags: android, velo

I am an Android Developer and 0 knowledge in Wix. Is it possible to get a list of products from Wix Store to display it on Android app. I cannot find any documentation for Android.

This is my test website
https://sakurafukuyoshi031.wixsite.com/juhachipawnshop/shop-1

I just want to know if it is possible to get the data so I can display it on my app from their API maybe by using javascript or the webview javascript injection methods Thanks

Comment: I don't think that they have Android API. But you can use WebView to load your store directly there. But why to do that if anyone can use a Web Browser to view your store instead of using your app based on the WebView?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you reply. I am also thinking that way. It is just that my superior asked me to take a look if I can get a list of products from Wix API using javascript. I am really having a hard time right now reading their documentation because I am not familiar with Wix and there's no Android documentation for me to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an API for Wix Stores just quite yet, but it's coming soon - https://www.wix.com/code/home/coming-soon

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to expose a collection by creating an API using the [wix-http-functions](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-http-functions.html) but it appears that it's limited to exposing custom collections - not Wix's native collections (Stores/Collections or Stores/Products). The example on the [wix-http-functions](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-http-functions.html) is pretty self explanatory. Below a modified version of it:

```
// In http-functions.js

import {ok, notFound, serverError} from 'wix-http-functions';
import wixData from 'wix-data';

// URL looks like:
// https://www.storename.com/_functions/storeProducts/1
// or
// https://user.wixsite.com/mysite/_functions/storeProducts/1


export function get_storeProducts(request) {
  let options = {
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };

  let pagesize=50;

  // query a collection to find matching items
  return wixData.query("Stores/Products") 
    // If you replace the "Stores/Products" with a custom collection name it works
    .skip((request.path[0] - 1) * pagesize)
    .limit(pagesize)
    .find()
    .then( (results) => {
      // matching items were found
      if(results.items.length > 0) {
        options.body = {
          "items": results.items
        };
        return ok(options);
      }
      // no matching items found
      options.body = {
        "error": `'${request.path[0]}' was not found`
      };
      return notFound(options);
    } )
    // something went wrong
    .catch( (error) => {
      options.body = {
        "error": error
      };
      return serverError(options);
    } );
}
```

Unfortunately this produces an error with the native collections such as "Products"

```
{"error":{"name":"Error","errorGroup":"User","code":"WD_SCHEMA_DOES_NOT_EXIST"}}
```

(I could not find any documentation for the error - so this is where I got stuck)

If you then create a custom collection in Wix Code under "Database", export the products from "Stores/Products" into a CSV - and then import the CSV into the custom collection (and finally publish/sync the custom collection) you can workaround the apparent limitation of exposing the native product catalog via a custom API. It's not ideal - but could work if your catalog is not changing frequently.